# Superclasse no catch

Tags: java, try-catch, superclasse

estou fazendo um curso de Java e me deparei com a seguinte questão:

> Explique detalhadamente os problemas relacionados e dê exemplos para cada uma das situações:
>
> 3 - O primeiro catch utiliza uma classe de erro que é superclasse daquela utilizada no segundo catch

Porém não entendi o que é uma superclasse. Essa questão é como um desafio no curso pois ainda não aprendemos isso. A estrutura `try-catch`  eu creio ter entendido, mas a questão da Superclasse realmente me pegou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando uma classe `extends` outra, é criada uma relação de herança. Por exemplo, em:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
```

Temos Exception como super classe de MyException. Mais sobre herança em Java [nesse link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)